# Proving the existence of a continuous function with same integral as another function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let f be a Riemann-integrable function in $[a,b]$. I have to prove that $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists g$ continuous , such that $ g \leq f$ and $\int_a^b f - \int_a^b g < \epsilon $.

I thought about aproximating the function with step functions and then aproximating them with linear functions. However, that way I can't satisfy the condition that $ g \leq f$.

Comment: Are you approximating $f$ with step functions *under* $f$? I assume you mean "and then approximating them with *piecewise*-linear functions"?

Comment: Since you can write $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$, it should suffice to show you can do this with $f\ge0$ and then apply a very similar reasoning to the piece $f^-$ (it won't be identical because you'll want the sum to be $\le f$ everywhere). So if $f\ge0$, then, with your simple function sufficiently close to $f$, try connecting the plateaus (i.e., where the simple function is constant) by "thinning" the interval. You'll have to choose "sufficiently close" and the thinning factor appropriately to get a continuous function $g$ with $|\int_a^b f -\int_a^b g|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: I will give the argument for approximating a step function by a continuous function from below when there is single step.  Suppose $h(x)=a$ for $x<x_0$ and $b$ for $x >x_0$ say with $a<b$. Define $g(x)=a$ for $x <x_0$, $g(x)=b$ for $x >x_0+\delta$ and $g(x)=\frac {b-a} {\delta} x+(a-x_0\frac {b-a} {\delta})$ for $x_0\leq x \leq x_0+\delta$. Then $g$ is  continuous, $g \leq h$ and $|g(x)-h(x)| \leq \max \{|a|,|b|\}$ for $x_0\leq x \leq x_0+\delta$. Since $g(x) =h(x)$ for other vales of $x$ it follows that $|\int g(x)-\int h(x)| \leq \delta \max \{|a|,|b|\}$. Choose $\delta$ so that $\delta \max \{|a|,|b|\} <\epsilon$.